# How are related Connected Component with Open-Closed Subset

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

I used to think that *connected components* were **closed** and **open** at the same time, but I discovered quite recently (italian page of *Wikipedia*) that this might not be the case.

What I'm asking for is:

1. an example to illustrate why it is not the case (i.e. an example for which the connected component are not open);
2. if there's some kind of statement or condition which specifies when they are open and closed.

Thank You

Comment: Let $X$ be any totally disconnected space; three familiar ones are $\Bbb Q$, $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$, and the Cantor set. Because these are totally disconnected, each component is a singleton; however, none of these spaces has an isolated point, so no singleton is open.

Comment: An example of a space with clopen connected components is the union of closed intervals in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I'm not sure I got your example... please could you expand it a little bit? Which topology are you putting on $X$, the Zarinski topology?

Comment: @Dac0: In the three specific examples that I gave I’m using the ordinary Euclidean topology inherited from $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Now I got it! Thank You! Since they're dense with that topology the singleton is not open. Great example.

Comment: @Dac0: You’re welcome.